# Codename One application works on simulator but crashes repeatedly on iPhone device

Tags: codenameone

After sending my first application to my iPhone, I find that it crashes repeatedly when using a navigation command or navigation from button action event, whereas the simulator does not.

I can't determine from the crash report (snippet below) what the cause is and wonder how I should go about debugging. I see that thread 2 triggered it (the crash) and was some invalid address or something? Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000021
Triggered by Thread:  2

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x376514f0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x376512e5 mach_msg + 37
2   CoreFoundation                  0x297fd317 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 143
3   CoreFoundation                  0x297fb8bd __CFRunLoopRun + 1013
4   CoreFoundation                  0x297493bd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 473
5   CoreFoundation                  0x297491cf CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
6   GraphicsServices                0x30b070a5 GSEventRunModal + 133
7   UIKit                           0x2cd58f9d UIApplicationMain + 1437
8   HelloWorld                      0x0067fc9b 0x51000 + 6483099
9   HelloWorld                      0x000aa8bb 0x51000 + 366779
10  HelloWorld                      0x002c352f 0x51000 + 2565423
11  HelloWorld                      0x0076103d 0x51000 + 7405629
12  HelloWorld                      0x00761097 0x51000 + 7405719
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x3759eaad start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37664b38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x376e13f5 _pthread_cond_wait + 517
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x376e2319 pthread_cond_timedwait + 41
3   HelloWorld                      0x0075dd77 0x51000 + 7392631
4   HelloWorld                      0x006af513 0x51000 + 6677779
5   HelloWorld                      0x006c8e21 0x51000 + 6782497
6   HelloWorld                      0x006c9a43 0x51000 + 6785603
7   HelloWorld                      0x0075e211 0x51000 + 7393809
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x376e1e91 _pthread_body + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x376e1e03 _pthread_start + 115
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x376dfb8c thread_start + 4

Thread 2 Crashed:
0   HelloWorld                      0x00726d99 0x51000 + 7167385
1   HelloWorld                      0x0071f625 0x51000 + 7136805
2   HelloWorld                      0x0071f28d 0x51000 + 7135885
3   HelloWorld                      0x0071ebc9 0x51000 + 7134153
4   HelloWorld                      0x000d2db5 0x51000 + 531893
5   HelloWorld                      0x002e89db 0x51000 + 2718171
6   HelloWorld                      0x002f11bf 0x51000 + 2752959
7   HelloWorld                      0x0044ad11 0x51000 + 4168977
8   HelloWorld                      0x00250247 0x51000 + 2093639
9   HelloWorld                      0x00276cb5 0x51000 + 2251957
10  HelloWorld                      0x00276dd3 0x51000 + 2252243
11  HelloWorld                      0x0030b8d1 0x51000 + 2861265
12  HelloWorld                      0x002d7ec9 0x51000 + 2649801
13  HelloWorld                      0x0030b721 0x51000 + 2860833
14  HelloWorld                      0x0030b17d 0x51000 + 2859389
15  HelloWorld                      0x0063b9a3 0x51000 + 6203811
16  HelloWorld                      0x006349d5 0x51000 + 6175189
17  HelloWorld                      0x00638d73 0x51000 + 6192499
18  HelloWorld                      0x006414e9 0x51000 + 6227177
19  HelloWorld                      0x005d3bb3 0x51000 + 5778355
20  HelloWorld                      0x0030aa21 0x51000 + 2857505
21  HelloWorld                      0x001e991d 0x51000 + 1673501
22  HelloWorld                      0x001ea153 0x51000 + 1675603
23  HelloWorld                      0x001eb2c9 0x51000 + 1680073
24  HelloWorld                      0x003213db 0x51000 + 2950107
25  HelloWorld                      0x0031fd21 0x51000 + 2944289
26  HelloWorld                      0x0023bf57 0x51000 + 2010967
27  HelloWorld                      0x002d4bcb 0x51000 + 2636747
28  HelloWorld                      0x002c778b 0x51000 + 2582411
29  HelloWorld                      0x002cd993 0x51000 + 2607507
30  HelloWorld                      0x004dffff 0x51000 + 4780031
31  HelloWorld                      0x000a80d3 0x51000 + 356563
32  HelloWorld                      0x006c9a43 0x51000 + 6785603
33  HelloWorld                      0x0075e211 0x51000 + 7393809
34  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x376e1e91 _pthread_body + 137
35  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x376e1e03 _pthread_start + 115
36  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x376dfb8c thread_start + 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a regression due to the switch to the [new Codename One VM](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-codename-one-ios-vm-is-now-the-default). You can follow the suggested temporary workaround in the post by using the build argument `ios.newVM=false` however I would suggest filing an issue in the issue tracker as well if you have a simple test case that crashes the new VM.